# What steps should I take to properly protect user input in PHP?

Tags: php, security, xss, sql-injection

What steps should I take to properly protect user input in PHP, so that I can prevent SQL injection and XSS attacks, while still allowing certain HTML tags? Is there a reliable function or method that serves this purpose comprehensively?

I don't know how to properly protect user input in PHP